# Dynamic image resize

Tags: css, image, dynamic, resize

I saw a very nice homepage on templatemonster and im trying to make my homepage look alike and the problem is the main image. it wont scale the same way and i have no idea what I should search for . i have searched for dynamic picture but cant find anything.

The site with the image script: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_43701/#!/pageSplash
Try to resize the window and you will see that the image will shrink and some parts of the image will move outside the window.

The site im working on is:
http://dq.se/formbar/
the main image has only one TAG and that is

`width:100%;`

Please help me find a way that my IMAGE has the min-height: 500px; and if the window gets smaller the image will be cut on the sides.

/ Axel

Comment: I failed to see any shrink effect. But anyway, you can use Chrome's DevTool or Firefox's Firebug extension to inspect the page and learn.

Comment: You can set it as a background image and use [`background-size: cover`](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), or this [jQuery plugin](http://christianvarga.com/blog/2011/05/jquery-resize-image-to-parent-container-plugin/) if it must be an image. Also, check your console, your code is returning a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1):

well if you have `min-height:500px;` try `overflow:hidden;` this will hide the rest of your picture after shrinking to 500px

little fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/523Vb/)

Comment: Yes that could work but the image will now disappear to the right side. i want the face and the hair to always be in focus. the most the picture can be "cut" is to the tip of her nose and to the end of her hair. tried to use:
'left:50%;' and marginleft:-50%; or something like that .

Comment: then you should jquery to fix it i think. or someone else needs to know the awnser mate